# check ssd from udevadm info

Tags: usb, udev, ssd, storage, lsblk

I have two peripherals(SSD and USB) connected to my system.

`Command: lsblk -S
Output:
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
sda  1:0:0:0    disk ATA      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   023  sata
sdb  2:0:0:0    disk Mushkin  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    0    usb`

How do I find from `udevadm info` that `sda` is SSD?

I checked with property `ID_ATA_ROTATION_RATE_RPM` of `udevadm info`. if this set to `0` then it is an SSD. But, when I checked this property with the devices(`sda & sdb`) it was set to `0` for both.

I cross-checked `sda` by running `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational` it returned `0`

whereas, for `sdb` by running `cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational` it returned `1`
*(I am not sure how it set `ID_ATA_ROTATION_RATE_RPM` to `0` for `sdb`)*

Is there any other way apart from `ID_ATA_ROTATION_RATE_RPM` from `udevadm info` that I can distinguish between SSD and other peripheral?